# how to get specific child with spacific attribute ..here is my firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my Firebase Realtime Database schema. I want to get passwords and usernames from all employees.

[image]

Is there a way to get a specific value of a child in the Realtime Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually get the user names and passwords from all employees, you have to create a reference that points to the "Employs" node, perform a `get()` call and attach a listener. So please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference employsRef = db.child("Admin").child("Employs");
employsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String password = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", name + "/" + password);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
usman/88568558458
```